# (Elementor) Can I add small animated gifs that overlap a slider?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I just got started with Elementor and want to create little animated sparkles that overlap a slider that will cycle through images of pastries on the home page. If this is possible, is there a way to make it responsive as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do this, i recommend you to give a look at Revolution slider plugin. With elementor, with the free version, i do not think such a thing is possible. The free one is very limited and don't really lets you customize elements as you'ld like.

You can also give a look at Divi's page builder, which is not free, but in my opinion is way better and way more customizable than elementor.